# Prove that the $\lim _\limits{x \to 1} (4/(3x+2))= 4/5$.

Tags: analysis

Use the definition of a limit to prove that the  $\lim _\limits{x \to 1} \frac 4 {3x+2}= \frac 4 5$.
For my scratch work I have:
$$|4/(3x+2) - 4/5| = |20/5(3x+2)-4(3x+2)/5(3x+2)| = |-12x-12/15x+10|$$

This is where I am stuck. I know somehow I need to get it so that $(x-1)$ is in there somehow but if I factor at a $12$ or $-12$ I get $12(-x-1)$ or $-12(x+1).$

I know I need to get $(x-1)$ somewhere so I can suppose that $|x-1| < 1$ so I can find the values that the other factor can fall into which I can then use to set my $\gamma = \min \{1,\_\_ \}.$

Comment: You have done a sign mistake. In the numerator we have $20 - 4(3x+2) = -12x + 12$. You can get your $(x-1)$ from that.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Given $ \epsilon >0$, we look for small $ \eta>0 $, smaller than $ 1$ by adding the condition

$$|x-1|<1 \iff 0<x<2$$
$$\iff \frac{1}{40}\frac{1}{5(3x+2)}<\frac{1}{10}$$

such that

$$|\frac{12}{5(3x+2)}|<\frac 65$$